# Need an email client thats for Android and Windows

Tags: windows, android, cross-platform, email-client

I'm after an email client that works on both Android and Windows.
Any recommendations?

Comment: For Windows, in my opinion [Mailbird](http://www.getmailbird.com) is the best.

Comment: I was looking for something cross-platform to work on my android phone and windows, i cant seam to find anything

Comment: What use is the same email client on both systems? It'll behave like two separate programs

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. For example: What features are important to you? Must it be the very same software on both systems (I'm not aware of any such, btw) – or could it be two different products?

Comment: Hi, i dont necessarily need the same software, im just one of those guys who like to have 1 thing for each thing i need, such as a single email client for email, im not sure what it is haha

Answer (score 1):

Request an invite for ["Inbox" by Google](http://www.google.com/inbox/). It has the same new material design on both Android and (in browser) on Windows.